# aws glue crawlers too slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Does glue crawlers have the function to crawl only certain folders under s3? Currently our pipeline is getting slower and slower since we continuously have new data coming in. We know certainly which folders are new and in which pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A Glue Crawler can be configured to only crawl specific paths from an S3 source (`Include path`). Additionally, if needed, a crawler can be configured to exclude certain file patterns (`Exclude patterns`).

Example `CreateCrawler` API request:

```json
{
   ...
   "Targets": { 
      "S3Targets": [ 
         { 
            "ConnectionName": "string",
            "Exclusions": [
               "file_pattern_to_exclude_1",  // <-- Exclude patterns
               "file_pattern_to_exclude_2",
            ],
            "Path": "s3://<bucket>/path/to/include",  // <-- Include path
            "SampleSize": number
         },
         {
            ...
         }
      ]
   },
   ...
}
```

References

1. [Crawler Properties (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html)
2. [CreateCrawler Glue Web API (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_CreateCrawler.html)
3. [S3Target Glue Web API (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_S3Target.html)

A Glue Crawler can be configured to behave in different ways when new files/folders are added to the include path in an S3 source. Specifically, a crawler can be configured to crawl only new files/folders; this is an `incremental crawl`.

**Note: There are restrictions for incremental crawls with respect to schema changes. Take some time to read through the AWS documentation. It's extensive and a bit scattered.**

Example `CreateCrawler` API request:

```json
{
   ...
   "RecrawlPolicy": {
      "RecrawlBehavior": "CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY"
   },
   "SchemaChangePolicy": {
      "UpdateBehavior": "LOG",
      "DeleteBehavior": "LOG",
   }
   ...
}
```

References

1. [Incremental Crawls in AWS Glue (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/incremental-crawls.html)
2. [Setting Crawler Configuration Options (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html)
3. [RecrawlPolicy Glue Web API (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_RecrawlPolicy.html)
4. [SchemaChangePolicy Glue Web API (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_SchemaChangePolicy.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new method where you use S3 bucket event notifications to track file changes and put them in an SQS queue, which is then specified in your crawler to only crawl files indicated in this SQS queue. This process is documented here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-s3-event-notifications.html

I can confirm that this works as I have implemented this in my own project.